# Moving completed badges down on selecting new 'Next badge'

Tags: feature-request, design, badges

I tried to select my new "Next-badge", but all my completed ones are on top of the badges I can choose. Wouldn't it be more logical to move the completed ones under (I will never ever choose those as "Next-badge") uncompleted badges?

[image]